# jQuery mobile input field item size

Tags: jquery, api, jquery-mobile, maps

I would like to use the search input field provided by jQuery mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/search/) for my mobile site.

I wonder why the suggestions of the box are so small and therefore hard to touch
on a mobile device. Is there a way to customize it via CSS?

Comment: Is it too small when you view it on the jQuery mobile demo site, or your site?

Answer (score 2):

Or just write:

```
.quantity { width: 40px !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change following coding in jquerymobile core css file.

```
input.ui-input-text, textarea.ui-input-text { background-image: none; padding: .4em; line-height: 1.4; font-size: 16px; display: block; width: 97%; }
```